# Remove documentation popup in Xcode 3.2

Tags: cocoa, xcode, osx-snow-leopard

When I alt(option) double-click a keyword in Xcode 3.2, I get the following popup:

[alt text http://www.noggin.co.za/popup.png](http://www.noggin.co.za/popup.png)

I absolutely hate it. Is there a way to go back to searching the documentation (as in Xcode 3.0) rather than popping up this dialog?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cmd+option double-click works for me.

Answer (score 2):

This won't stop the pop-up from appearing, but you can click the book icon in its upper-right corner to move to the Documentation Viewer.

Comment: Thanks. I wish I could make it go away altogether. I even tried finding a plist entry for this but couldn't.

Answer (score 1):

God I hate it too!!!  I want it to just go back to the way it was, or at least let us choose!!!  WTF Apple???  You're not really enhancing a developer's life if you force them to change for no apparent reason!  If you wanted this new functionality, you make this have a NEW keyboard shortcut and leave the old ones alone!!!